# Ticket meta-search engine with alliance filter?

Tags: online-resources, flight-search-engines, airline-alliances

Is there a ticket meta-search engine?

E.g. Skyscanner has a filter that can remove or keep the airline brands. (Un-)checkboxing them one by one is irritating.

**But is there one where I can just (un-)checkbox alliances?** e.g. "Star Alliance", "Sky Team", "One World", etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can try [Kayak](https://www.kayak.com/)! It contains an alliance filter!

Comment: Cool! Now that saves lots of clicking...

Comment: Amazing, they have payment type filters too!

Answer (score 7):

The [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) can do this (obviously. ITA Matrix can do everything and then some and then some more). So says the [wiki](http://flyerguide.com/Matrix_by_ITA_Software#SEARCHING_BY_ALLIANCE):

> from: BOS ::/ alliance oneworld

Answer (score 6):

[Kayak](https://www.kayak.com) has alliance filters (on the left, you can filter between carrier and alliance filters). [Hipmunk](http://www.hipmunk.com) also lets you filter by alliance under "airlines." [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) works much the same way.